# Is there any way to get the list of names of views having a decorator, Python, Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-decorators

I have a views.py file like this

*views.py*

```
@my_decorator
def a(request):
    return HttpResponse("success")

@my_decorator
def b(request):
    return HttpResponse("success")

@my_decorator
def c(request):
    return HttpResponse("success")

@my_decorator
def d(request):
    return HttpResponse("success")

@my_another_decorator
def e(request):
    return HttpResponse("success")
```

I want to get a list of views having decorator "my_decorator"

Example:

```
views_list_with_my_decorator=["a","b","c","d"]
```

please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
decorated = []
def myDecorator(fn):
    decorated.append(fn)
    ...
```

maybe? but it will only work if they have been decorated (ie imported or otherwise "ran" ... it will not work if they are just sitting off in .py files somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do some trick with the docorator. The following is my solution. Just for your inspiration. You could have a try :)

```
from functools import wraps

def my_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func()
    wrap_func.decorator = my_decorator.func_name
    return wrap_func

def my_another_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func()
    wrap_func.decorator = my_another_decorator.func_name
    return wrap_func

@my_decorator
def a(request):
    pass

@my_decorator
def b(request):
    rpass

@my_decorator
def c(request):
    pass

@my_decorator
def d(request):
    pass

@my_another_decorator
def e(request):
    pass

func_list_with_my_decorator = [e for e in globals().values() if getattr(e, 'decorator', None)=='my_decorator']

print func_list_with_my_decorator
```

If you want to try whether a function has a decorator, do like this:

```
print a.decorator == 'my_decorator'
```